# Initializing button message with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that is looping through an array of tasks. There is a button for each task where one can click and see options to assign a date and user. I want to set the message of the button to show what user/date (if any) are assigned per task (like on Basecamp). So if nothing was assigned the message would be "unassigned : no due date", if both were assigned it would say "Steve Ballmer : 08/12/2015". I have tried initializing the message with:

```
ng-init="setOptionsMessage(task)
```

The problem is that it is passing in the same task id on every loop. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the ng-repeat line to help illustrate what you are doing.  However, I believe you need to call a function and return the information as the data for the button.

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat='button in buttons'>
        <button ng-click="DoSomething(button.Action)">>{{button.Title}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is assuming that the controller has populated the title based on data retrieved.  You could do it dynamically as well, but this is a quick simple example to help get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share some code? I don't understand exactly your problem, but maybe this could help:
http://plnkr.co/edit/oKxIk8Dg8nyCy3PxmS82?p=preview

Maybe it should be only comment, but I don't have enough reputation to make comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. I did something like mentioned above. I run an init function on each li, each one belonging to a task. Here is the init function:

```
  $scope.setOptionsMessage = function(task) {
    if(task.asigneeId) {
      task.optionsMessage = $scope.fullName(task.user);
      task.optionsMessage += ' | ';
    }
    else {
      task.optionsMessage = 'Not assigned | ';
    }

    if(task.dueDate) {
      task.optionsMessage += 'Due on: ' + task.dueDate;
    } 
    else if(task.dueEvent === $scope.NEXT_APPOINTMENT) {
      task.optionsMessage += 'Due at next appointment';
    }
    else {
      task.optionsMessage += 'No due date';
    }
  }
```

This adds an optionsMessage property to each task object so that it can be used as the message for each task. Here is the html(slim) related to that portion of code:

```
li [ng-repeat='task in uncompletedTasks' ng-init="setOptionsMessage(task)" class='patient-task repeated-item']
  span ng-hide="editing"
    input type="checkbox" ng-click="markComplete(task)"
    span class="task-text" {{task.text}}

    span class="task-popover-link" 
      span class="click-link" ng-click="optionsShow=!optionsShow"
        | {{task.optionsMessage}}
```